# Using .reduce to Wrap React Exports

Tags: reactjs

When using many higher order functions I have found that the exports in a React project can get very messy. For example using `react-redux`, `react-router`, `redux-form` and `react-i18next` can look like:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    // stuff
  }
};

const form = {
  // stuff
};

export default withRouter(withTranslation()(reduxForm(form)(connect(mapStateToProps)(Component)))));
```

This can get pretty unwieldy and keeping track of and changing the order can get messy. I created a simple one-liner to wrap the exports:

**wrapper.js**

```
export default ({ component, wrappers }) => wrappers.reduce((acc, wrapper) => wrapper(acc), component);
```

To be used like so:

```
import wrapper from '../path/to/wrapper.js';

/* rest of code */

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    // stuff
  }
};

const form = {
  // stuff
};

export default wrapper({
  component: Component,
  wrappers: [
    // The order of the wrappers can be changed by just changing
    // the order in which they appear here
    connect(mapStateToProps),
    reduxForm(form),
    withTranslation,
    withRouter,
  ],
});
```

So far this has worked, my question is: are there any potential issues with this approach that might not be immediately apparent? And are there any other ways or best practices for managing React exports?